# The data size returned from the android webview loadurl is too large

Tags: android, android-webview

I'm trying to load a JavaScript page

But the data read is too big

So I can't read them all at once

Below is the source code

Is there a way to get all the webpage information?

Thank you

```
String url = "https://finance.daum.net/exchanges?view=pc";

webView = new WebView(this);

webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
//webView.getSettings().setDatabaseEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new MyJavascriptInterface(), "Android");


webView.setWebViewClient(new FirstWebViewClient());

webView.loadUrl(url);

public class FirstWebViewClient extends WebViewClient
{
    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) 
    {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);

        //view.loadUrl("javascript:window.Android.getHtml(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML);");
        view.loadUrl("javascript:Android.getHtml(document.getElementsByClassName('exchage')[0].innerHTML);");
    }
}


public class MyJavascriptInterface 
{
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void getHtml(String html) 
    {
        readHtml = html;

        new AppTask().execute();

    }
}
```

Comment: Post the actual error and how you came to that conclusion.

Comment: No error occurs
But I can't read the entire html source of the webpage
If the total source character is 50,000, only 10,000 can be read.